# Monthview Bolding Every Value

Tags: vba, excel, monthcalendar

I created a Monthview and TimePicker in a form.  I want the user to pick the time, and select a month which will bold the value selected each time, then select OK which will insert the value.  I have all of this working fine.  The issue is that if a user selects a date, then selects another date, or another date, all the dates are getting Bolded.  I want the BOLD to only follow each most recent click.. if that makes sense, so that the user knows what value he chose.

Here is my click code:

```
  Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)

 Dim x As Date

    x = MonthView1.value
    MonthView1.DayBold(x) = True ' Bold the date

End Sub
```

What method do I need? Is there some kind of most-recent clicked property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)

Dim x As Date
Dim MaxDate As Date
Dim MinDate As Date

MinDate = DateSerial(Year(DateClicked), Month(DateClicked), 1) 'Get first date of current month based on clicked date
MaxDate = DateSerial(Year(DateClicked), Month(DateClicked) + 1, 0) 'Get last date of current month based on clicked date

x = ActiveCell.Value 'Retreive value of last Bold date
If x >= MinDate And x <= MaxDate Then 'If last Bold date is in the current month then unbold it
    MonthView1.DayBold(x) = False
End If

MonthView1.DayBold(DateClicked) = True 'Bold the clicked date
ActiveCell.Value = DateClicked 'Store current date in a sheet

End Sub
```

The idea is to save the Bold date in a sheet (you may hide it if you wish) and retrieve it when another date is selected. The Bold formatting is removed from the previous date and applied to the current one.

Comment: Nice Fix Zeno.  for the first x= I can just set it to x = ActiveCell.value, no need to look for a specific cell.  Here's the issue:  If I select a date, it populates, all good.  If i reclick on the cell and select another date IN ANOTHER MONTH, it errors the code out with a "A date was specified that does not fall within the MinDate and MaxDate properties".  This error does not occur unless I  change pages and select another month.. any reason to why this is occurring?

Comment: Nevermind I just put an Error Handler and it fixed it ! Great solution ZENO!

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long to reply. I'm glad you found a way around that issue. I have edited the code I posted initially to also overcome this. As I understand the problem is that when you select a date in another month the the Min and Max dates change to the first and last dates of that month so when we try to format a date in another month we get the error. At the same time any formatting applied to dates in other months is lost. So we only need to remove the formatting if selecting a date in the same month as the previous date otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

a bit more on bolding in a  MonthView

```
'<code>
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim Ss(50) As Boolean

  'put  in module  DaysToBold$  and DatesToBold$  as public variables
  DaysToBold = "713"  ' sat Sun Tue
  ' DaysToBold = "" ' for none
  DatesToBold = "x,1,2,12,22,30"
 ' DatesToBold = "x" ' if none

  MonthView21_GetDayBold Now, 49, Ss

End Sub

Private Sub MonthView21_GetDayBold(ByVal StartDate As Date, _
            ByVal Count As Integer, State() As Boolean)
  Dim I As Integer, Mi%, DTB, DI%, DAd%
  On Error Resume Next ' seem to be  negative indices into State() even if declared  ( -10 to 50)

  For Mi = 1 To Len(DaysToBold)  ' mark of the Days of week to bold
    I = Mid(DaysToBold, Mi, 1)  ' single digits 1 ..7  excel translate to integer
    While I < Count
        State(I - MonthView21.StartOfWeek) = True
        I = I + 7  ' down the column
    Wend
  Next Mi


  DTB = Split(DatesToBold, ",")
  If UBound(DTB) > 0 Then
    With MonthView21
        For I = 1 To UBound(DTB)  ' mark the date numbers to bold
          DI = Weekday(DateSerial(Year(.Value), Month(.Value), 1), .StartOfWeek)
         If DI = 1 Then DAd = 5 Else DAd = -2  ' 7 days of last month there if Di=1
            State(DTB(I) + DI + DAd) = True
        Next I
    End With
  End If
End Sub
'</code>
```